# Use environment variable on tomcat 10.0.26-jdk8

Tags: java, tomcat, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm creating a new docker image for deploying an application, but I'm not able to use the variable environment to configure my datasource. I already used other syntaxes to declare environment variable (DB_URL,${env.DB_URL},{DB_URL}[DB_URL]), is there something that I have to configure?

- Version from tomcat: **tomcat:10.0.26-jdk8**
- web.xml from tomcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--   Licensed to the    Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more   contributor    license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with   this work    for additional information regarding copyright ownership.   The ASF    licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0      (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with     the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
   
     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,      WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or    implied.   See the License for the specific language governing    permissions and   limitations under the License.    --> <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
    define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
    Documentation at /docs/config/server.html  --> <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">   <Listener    className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />      <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener"    />   -->   <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html    -->   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"    SSLEngine="on" />   <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of    particular java/javax APIs-->   <Listener    className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"    />   <Listener    className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"    />   <Listener    className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"    />
     <!-- Global JNDI resources
      Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html   -->   <GlobalNamingResources>    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
        UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users    -->    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
             type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
             description="User database that can be updated and saved"
             factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
             pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
       <Resource name="jdbc/myapp"
         auth="Container"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
         url="jdbc:mysql://${DB_URL}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SCHEMA}?autoReconnect=true"
         defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
         username="${DB_USER}"  
         password="${DB_PWD}"
         testOnBorrow="true"
         validationQuery="SELECT 1"
         validationInterval="${DB_VAL_INTERVAL}"
         maxActive="${DB_MAX_ACTIV}"
         maxIdle="${DB_IDLE}"
         minIdle="${DB_MIN_IDLE}" />   </GlobalNamingResources>
     <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that    share
      a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
      so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
      Documentation at /docs/config/service.html    -->   <Service name="Catalina">
       <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->    <!--    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
       maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>    -->
   
       <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
        and responses are returned. Documentation at :
        Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
        Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
        APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
        Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080    -->    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->    <!--    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
              port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="8443" />    -->    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
        This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
        SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
        library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the AprLifecycleListener.
        Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
        the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.    -->    <!--    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
       <SSLHostConfig>
           <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                        type="RSA" />
       </SSLHostConfig>    </Connector>    -->    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
        This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
        OpenSSL for TLS.
        Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
        configuration is used below.    -->    <!--    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
       <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
       <SSLHostConfig>
           <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                        certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                        certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                        type="RSA" />
       </SSLHostConfig>    </Connector>    -->
       <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->    <!--    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
              address="::1"
              port="8009"
              redirectPort="8443" />    -->
       <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
        every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
        analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
        on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
        Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->
       <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">    -->    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
   
     <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
         /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
         /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
     <!--
     <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
     -->
   
     <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
          via a brute-force attack -->
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
       <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
            resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
            that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
            available for use by the Realm.  -->
       <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
              resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
     </Realm>
   
     <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   
       <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
            Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
       <!--
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
       -->
   
       <!-- Access log processes all example.
            Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
            Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
              prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
              pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   
     </Host>    </Engine>   </Service> </Server>
```

- **Error example:**

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
                at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
                at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
                at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:842)
                ... 33 more
        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${DB_URL}
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1287)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1199)
                at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:130)
                at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
                ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get environment variable on tomcat any version and any xml, follow this steps:

1. Create a new environment variable calling `CATALINA_OPTS`;
2. Set this value into a variable created on step 1 `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource`;
3. After followed steps previsious, you must create yours variables, and calling in your variable into XML using this syntax: `${ENV_VAR}`